# Input fields values taken state cannot be modified

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I cannot modify input predefined value.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  userDetails: this.props.location.state.userDetails,
  token: "",
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  roles: []
};
```

This is the method that I use for handling input:

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
const target = e.target;
const value = target.value;
const name = target.name;
this.setState = {
  [name]: value,
};
```

};

This is the input element:

```
 <input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.userDetails.firstName}
  name="firstName"
  ref="firstName"
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
 />
```

In the UI I cannot delete its(input) default value taken from the state neither type something else. If I comment the value this problem disappears.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: I think the problem is that you update `firstName` and read value of `userDetails.firstName`

Comment: Even if I do this, it has the same problem...

Comment: Like @NadiaChibrikova mentions it looks like you're storing the values in two places in state. Which one should it be?

Comment: Commenting out the value just makes it an uncontrolled component, so it looks like its a solution but it really isn't what you want

Comment: True, I want when the component renders to show those default values.

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` element always reads its value from `this.state.userDetails.firstName`, which doesn't change.

Because of that, `<input>`'s value has to be `firstName`:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.firstName}
  ...
```

Then you can, for instance, set `firstName: this.props.location.state.userDetails.firstName` as default value on first render.

Comment: I`ve tried this way as well, and still the state is not getting updated on onChange method.

Comment: I made it to work by using a normal function instead of an arrow function in the handleInputChange method..